# How to set caption for multiselect dropdownlist in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-chosen

Hi I am developing one asp.net application with jquery. I have one dropdownlistbox with multiselect options. On page load i want to display Select Any in dropodwnlistbox and currently first value(I am binding from database) is displaying.

I am binding values to dropdown in server side as below.

```
 ddlvendorss.DataSource = VendorsDropDownDT;
                ddlvendorss.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlvendorss.DataValueField = "Vendor_ID";
                ddlvendorss.DataBind();
```

This is my asp.net dropdownlistbox.

```
<b>Awarded To:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:ListBox ID="ddlvendorss" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" class="limitedNumbSelect"></asp:ListBox>
```

This is my jquery code.

```
$(function () {
        $(".limitedNumbSelect").chosen();
    });
```

My problem is I want to give some caption such as Select any name but my dropdown displaying database value. May I know how can i fix it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#ddlvendorss").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>select any name</option>");
```

In case of IE =< 8 you should do it like this:

```
$("#ddlvendorss").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>select any name</option>");
$("#ddlvendorss")[0].options[0].selected = true;
```

And if you want to do it from code behind:

```
ddlvendorss.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select any name", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ddlvendorss.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));
```